# Optimize shortest path calculation in an osmnx network

Tags: python, optimization, networkx, igraph, osmnx

My question is rather simple. I have to calculate the shortest path between all nodes in an osmnx network. However this takes an enormous amount of time. I was wondering if there was anything that could speed up/optimize the process. Thank you in advance.

**Here is the code:**

```
import osmnx as ox
import igraph as ig
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import random as rd
from IPython.display import clear_output
ox.config(log_console=True, use_cache=True)


%%time
city = 'Portugal, Lisbon'
G = ox.graph_from_place(city, network_type='drive')

G_nx = nx.relabel.convert_node_labels_to_integers(G)

weight = 'length'

G_ig = ig.Graph(directed=True)
G_ig.add_vertices(list(G_nx.nodes()))
G_ig.add_edges(list(G_nx.edges()))
G_ig.vs['osmid'] = list(nx.get_node_attributes(G_nx, 'osmid').values())
G_ig.es[weight] = list(nx.get_edge_attributes(G_nx, weight).values())

assert len(G_nx.nodes()) == G_ig.vcount()
assert len(G_nx.edges()) == G_ig.ecount()
nodes, edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G, nodes=True, edges=True) 

%%time
L_back_total = []
L_going_total =[]
i=1

for element in G_nx.nodes:

    clear_output(wait=True)
    L_going=[]
    L_back=[]
    
    for node in G_nx.nodes:
        
        length_going = G_ig.shortest_paths(source=element, target=node, weights=weight)[0][0]
        length_back = G_ig.shortest_paths(source=node, target=element, weights=weight)[0][0]
        
        L_going.append(length_going)
        L_back.append(length_back)

    L_back_total.append(length_back)
    L_going_total.append(length_going)
    print('Progress:', np.round(i/len(G_nx.nodes)*100, 5))
    i+=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the examples provided with osmnx, there is a notebook about routing-speed-time that shows how to parallelize the calculations

Comment: Wow you are absolutely correct. I haven't been checking the updates made on the examples. Thank you for telling me!

Comment: notebook: https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/blob/v0.16.0/notebooks/02-routing-speed-time.ipynb

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the Floyd-Warshall Algorithm.

Documentation:
https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.dense.floyd_warshall.html

Usage:

```
nx.floyd_warshall(G_ig)
```

Comment: The algorithm calculates the shortest path from A to B, but does it also calculate from B to A? Because in directed graphs theses paths will not be the same